# Multi-Modal Image Alignment Issue

Tags: c++, matlab, optimization, itk

I am trying to align two multi-spectral images using multi-modal image registration techniques.

I built a prototype in MATLAB by first creating the `optimizer` and `metric` objects as follows:

```
[optimizer, metric] = imregconfig('Multimodal');
```

This creates an optimizer object of type `OnePlusOneEvolutionaryOptimizer` and metric of type `MattesMutualInformation`. The images are aligned as follows:

```
tform = imregtform(movingImage, fixedImage, 'rigid', optimizer, metric);

aligned = imwarp(movingImage,tform,'OutputView',imref2d(size(fixedImage)));
```

Then I went for a C++ implementation of the same algorithm which is offered by [one of the examples](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/Examples_2RegistrationITKv4_2ImageRegistration11_8cxx-example.html) in the [ITK v4](https://itk.org/) library.

This example also gives correct results but here is the problem... The ITK version is way slower than the MATLAB version. I played around with the optimizer parameters and was able to speed it up a bit, but not comparable to MATLAB version.

MATLAB documentation of [`OnePlusOneEvolutionaryOptimizer`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/registration.optimizer.oneplusoneevolutionary.html) states that the value of `InitialRadius` property is **directly** proportional to the algorithm's execution speed (compromising on robustness). The confusion here is that in ITK, the value of `InitialRadius` is **inversely** proportional to the execution speed as far as I tested.

I couldn't find literature/documentation describing how the optimizer parameters like `InitialRadius` and `GrowthFactor` are interpreted in ITK. Please help in providing explanation of these parameters and speeding up the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is making sure you are compiling your program in Release mode, not Debug mode.

[Documentation](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1OnePlusOneEvolutionaryOptimizer.html) and [source code](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/master/Modules/Numerics/Optimizers/src/itkOnePlusOneEvolutionaryOptimizer.cxx) for **1+1** optimizer in ITK are available online.